# Pandas column separation using .loc

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I am an amateur user.
I watched many videos but I couldn't figure out this error.

[image: Code]

How can I keep `PERSON_WGHT`, `LOS`, and `IDC_DC_CD_1` as a columns for all rows that is 386816.

Comment: `df.loc[:, ['PERSON_WGHT', 'LOS', 'IDC_DC_CD_1']]`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.
[Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to select multip0le columns from all the records then use df[[column_list]].

```
df_new = df[['PERSON_WGHT', 'LOS', 'IDC_DC_CD_1']]
```